# compact lie group -> real analytic orbits in $\mathfrak{g}^*$

Tags: real-analysis, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group and $\mathfrak{g}$ the corresponding Lie algebra. Now, $G$ also acts on $\mathfrak{g}^*$, the dual of the Lie algebra, by the coadjoint-action.

My question now is: are the orbits of the $G$-action in $\mathfrak{g}^*$ real analytic? And if so, why and where could I read about it?

Edit: From the comment we know, that $G$ acts linearly on $\mathfrak{g}^*$ and $G$ can be endowed with some real analytic structure. But how does that imply, that the $G$-orbits are real analytic?

Comment: Since the group is a real analytic Lie group (all smooth Lie groups are analytic in exactly one way), everything you get out of it in such a natural way is analytic.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I heard this fact already, but I'd like to understand, why it is that way. So, we know that $G$ is real analytic and the action is also real analytic, since it acts by linear actions. But how do we conclude from that, that the orbits are real analytic?

Comment: How do you conclude that when you have a smooth Lie group acting smooth on a smooth manifold the orbits are smooth?

Comment: Hmm... maybe the fastest way would be to use the Lie exponential and to use, that it is a local homeomorphism and then endow the orbit $G \cdot x$ with the structure given by the lie algebra?

Comment: Another way would be to use the quotient topology to get a smooth structure on $G/G_x$ and then using the $G$-equivariant bijective map $G/G_x \to G \cdot x$ to get a smooth structure on $G \cdot x$. So the question would be: why is the structure on $G/G_x$ real analytic? It is so on $G$, but on the quotient?

Comment: I suggest you take Lee's textbook on smooth manifolds to see how this works in the smooth case.